# Rename file on zgrep results

Tags: bash, shell

**Problem:**

I've several `.gz` files e.g. `testfile1.gz`, `testfile2.gz`, etc.

I'm trying to `zgrep` each of these files and redirect the output to new files  having the same name, but *without the extension*. How can I do that?

**What I've tried:**

I tried the following, but this doesn't remove the extension (`.gz`):

```
for file in hello*; do zgrep 'line' $file > $file.TEST ; done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
for file in hello*.gz; do
    zgrep 'line' > "${file%.gz}.TEST"
done
```

From TLDP on [Manipulating Strings](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html):

> ${string%substring} #Deletes shortest match of $substring from back of $string.

Answer (score 1):

The `basename` command is your friend:

`for file in hello*; do zgrep 'line' "$file" > $(basename "$file" .gz); done`

Alternatively, simply remove '.gz' from the output file's name:

`for file in hello*; do zgrep 'line' "$file" > $(sed 's/.gz//' <<< "$file"); done`

Comment: This will create empty files for unsuccessful matches.

Comment: the `-s` option does not seem to be portable: [man basename](https://linux.die.net/man/1/basename)

Comment: I get invalid option for basenmae
basename: invalid option -- 's'
ambigiguous redirect

Comment: Edited the answer.